# Images not rendering on a next.js project deployed on Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, frontend, firebase-hosting

I am trying out Next.js for the first time. I have built a website and tried hosting it on firebase hosting. Everything else works fine but images are not being rendered on the hosted site.
My project has folders project and src at root level.
Images are saved in public in png format. They are imported and used in pages saved at location src/conatainers/homeContainer and src/conatainers/homeContainer. the images render correctly on local server, but are not working on hosted site.
`npm run build` does not create a build folder in next.js.
I am running the following code to deploy on firebase.

```
firebase experiments:enable webframeworks
firebase init hosting
firebase deploy
```

Firebase deploy creates a build folder with my png's in build/static/media folder.
It seems to be a result of the fact that next.js support is an experimental feature on firebase. Is there a fix for this issue?

I tried modifying my next.config.js file to

```
const nextConfig = {
    output: "export", // (optional) Set your desired output configuration
    images: {
      unoptimized: true,
    },}
```

It did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Next js  `output: "export",` create build in **out** directory not in build folder.

If you want Next js to make your build with name build folder you could try this,

```
const nextConfig = {
    output: "export", // (optional) Set your desired output configuration
    distDir:"build",
    images: {
      unoptimized: true,
    },
}
```

Comment: If it works you can accept it as answer, Best of luck for the future Development 